# How to understand the `::` in the python config file?

Tags: python, openstack

From the github address:

https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/master/setup.cfg

In the `setup.cfg`, there is code below:

```
[metadata]
name = nova
summary = Cloud computing fabric controller
description-file =
    README.rst
author = OpenStack
author-email = openstack-dev@lists.openstack.org
home-page = http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/
classifier =
    Environment :: OpenStack
    Intended Audience :: Information Technology
    Intended Audience :: System Administrators
    License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
    Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 2
    Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
```

The contents in the `[]` means config name. such as `name` means key, the below means value.

but how about the `Environment :: OpenStack`, does the `::` have practical meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `::` has no special meaning other that that's the picked delimiter for [Trover classifier levels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers).

The classifiers are just metadata, helping people find specific packages and learn what the package is about. The package maintainer picks these when writing the `setup.py` script; the `setup.cfg` file is an alternative way of specifying the same.

Answer (score 1):

The double-colon, in this case, is the classifier namespace separator. It is not Python syntax, it's the naming conventions for the categories on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org).